# Perfomance consideration for a chat server using MongoDB/mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to learn MongoDB and for that implementing a chat server, using mongoose in the middleware.

I have a collection for messaging between two or more people lets name it chats,
an entry for a chat is something like and I believe it is self-explanatory ;

`{
    "_id": "????",
    "roomName": "room2",
    "who": "VTAF",
    "message": "hello",
    "__v": 0,
    "time": "2015-09-16T20:05:55.863Z"
  }`

SO I am currently storing all the chat history as flatten as possible since time and context of the message is important, should be searchable.

Is it reasonable to store the data as I did or would it cause performance issues?

Answer (score 0):

Saving the message like this should have no problem in performance.. but if you want to be very fast in searching in text i would consider using ElasticSearch, but for this you would have to keep in sync 2 databases. Mongodb and elasticsearch.

While if you think it is a secondary feature ( searching ) just mongo will be ok